# Empty Result on Pandas Merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one large DataFrame `prices` with three columns - id, date, and price. See a sample below:

```
    id  date        price
0   1st 2022-09-11  3.4
1   1st 2022-09-10  43.2
2   1st 2022-09-09  8.1
3   1st 2022-09-08  32.2
4   2nd 2022-09-11  10.4
5   2nd 2022-09-10  41.1
6   2nd 2022-09-09  6.5
7   2nd 2022-09-08  39.3
```

I have another smaller DataFrame, called `results`, with four columns - id, date, color, and size.

```
    id  date        color   size
0   1st 2022-09-11  blue    s
1   1st 2022-09-10  red     m
2   2nd 2022-09-09  green   xl
```

I want to merge the `price` column from `volumes` into `results` based on matching `id` and `date`, such that there is a new column `price` in the `results` DataFrame. Based on the examples above, here's what `results` should be after the merge operation:

```
    id  date        color   size   price
0   1st 2022-09-11  blue    s      3.4
1   1st 2022-09-10  red     m      43.2
2   2nd 2022-09-09  green   xl     6.5
```

When I do `results = pd.merge(results, prices)`, I get an empty DataFrame. What is going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Because it was asked for in the comments, here are `results.dtypes` and `prices.dtypes`

`prices.dtypes`:

```
id        object
date      object
price    float64
```

`results.dtypes`:

```
id       object
date     object
color    object
size     object
```

Comment: Can you provide `results.dtypes` and `prices.dtypes` ?

Comment: Can you post a working example? When I merge, I get the table you want. Its not really right... its based on the index, not id and date, but its not empty either.

Comment: `pd.merge(results, prices, on=["id", "date"])` should do it.

Comment: @NickODell added the `dtypes` for each

Comment: A little strange, but the result is the same as you expect. version pandas 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Pandas Merge Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) you need to specify a target to merge with. It appears that you are calling the pandas library to merge, when it should be `prices.merge(results)`. If the specific column order you posted is required, take a look at the keyword how in the docs.

Comment: I don't think that's true. If you look at that documentation, you'll see the `on` parameter says this: "If on is None and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames." But that's what OP wants to do - they want a merge by id and date.

Comment: My bad, I believe you're correct. However, dropping on should set it to id. From what I am reading prices.merge(results) should also work.